# find all audio files in a folder using bash in linux

Tags: linux, bash, find, ls

When I am using wildcards with `ls` command, it works.

```
$ ls '*.{mp3,ogg}'  # Showing only two formats in the command
cannot access *.mp3: No such file or directory
1.ogg 2.ogg 3.ogg
```

but using find command doesn't work

```
$ find ~ -iname '*.{mp3,ogg}'
```

What is the error in the line?

Comment: Brace expansion and pathname expansion is not done for quoted words, so you must've run `ls *.{mp3,ogg}` to get that output, not `ls '*.{mp3,ogg}'`

Comment: what about m4a files etc? you should rely on `file` instead.

Comment: Using the "file" utility and grep on "audio" unfortunately is NOT relable, as the file output is not well defined.
E.g. on an AAC audio file it reports:
MPEG ADTS, AAC, v4 LC, 44.1 kHz, stereo Also you may find avi video files with audio (most likeliy with videos ...)
E.g. on an avi file it reports:
RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 672 x 368, 25.00 fps, video: XviD, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz) Thus using "file" gives false positives and also false negatives.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this should work for you

```
   find ~ -name "*.mp3" -o -name "*.ogg"
```

-o is equivalent to boolean `or`

Answer (score 4):

If you enable extglob (`shopt -s extglob`), you can use `*.@(ogg|mp3)`.

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' *.@(mp3|ogg)
```

If you need recursion too, enable globstar (requires bash 4.0 or newer)

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
printf '%s\n' **/*.@(mp3|ogg)
```

When you use `ls *.{mp3,ogg}`, you are combining brace expansion and pathname expansion. What happens is:

```
ls *.{mp3,ogg}  
ls *.mp3 *.ogg  # after brace expansion
ls '*.mp3' 1.ogg 2.ogg 3.ogg # after pathname expansion
```

If there's no matching files for a glob, the glob will just be passed on unchanged. And `ls` will treat it as a literal filename; it doesn't know about globs/wildcards.

The `find ~ -iname '*.{mp3,ogg}'`  doesn't work because `find` doesn't do brace expansion, that's a bash feature.

Answer (score 4):

This one provides you with even those files which do *not* have mp3 or audio extension.

```sh
find -print0 | xargs -0 file -F '//' | awk -F '//' 'tolower($2) ~ /audio/ { print $1 }'
```

---

which interprets to:

`find . -print0` 
Find (list) every file and output with a null terminator

`xargs -0 file -F '//'` Run `file(1)` with the stdin (or piped input),  delimited by null character,   as the first argument.

`file -F '//'` Delimit file name and its type by `//` as it neither appears in a UNIX filename nor as a file type.

`awk -F '//' '...'`  Use the `//` delimiter as field separator. The awk script case-insensitively matches the occurrence of `audio` in the second field (ie the file type as reported by `file(1)`) and for every match, prints the file path.

Comment: This will also match files with 'audio' in their path, whether they are truly audio files or not.

Comment: @BenAmos Yes, you're right. I've updated the answer to fix that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one I just did . . .

for .ogg and .mp3

```
         find Music | grep '/*.ogg\|/*.mp3' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` does not support the full shell wildcard syntax (specifically, not the curly braces). You'll need to use something like this:

```
find ~ -iname '*.mp3' -o -iname '*.ogg'
```

Answer (score 0):

what about?

```
file * | grep audio
```

Comment: This one wouldn't check in subdirectories.

Comment: `find . -exec file {} \; | grep audio -i`, however, this doesn't work for all audio files

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -exec file {} --mime-type \; | grep "audio\|video"
```

might do the trick. The mime type of my m4a files is `video/mp4`, so I need to grep for that as well.

Comment: is the `video` bit needed? Searching for video files is tricky due to mp4, as we'd have to grep for something like `video/|audio/mp4`. But for sound files, grepping for `audio` should suffice.